# Java - Issue with calling abstract method during instantiation in super before child fields have been set

Tags: java, constructor, parent, abstract, super

This is my first time using these forums, so I hope this thread is appropriate and that I don't mess up. This is in **Java** - I'll try and simplify the example to focus on the main problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Say I have two classes, **Parent** and **Child**, where Parent is an abstract class and Child extends Parent. (I'm writing this code on the fly)...

```
public abstract class Parent {
    // A bunch of fields that have been omitted...
    public Parent() {
        print(getX());
    }

    public abstract int getX();
}
```

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    private int x;

    public Child(int x) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

I want to instantiate Child, and call an abstract method immediately after instantiation. Obviously, currently there is an issue because the x field hasn't been set when getX() is called in the parent from super(), and therefore will always return 0.

However, I want this to be done in the parent for all children of Parent (if there is a Child2, Child3, etc. that extend Parent in the future). i.e. anything that extends Parent will have their "x" value printed. The work around to this would be to print getX() with every Child that is instantiated, but for some reason, it seems rather off to me to have to do this repeatedly inside every Child class, as opposed to having this captured in the Parent.

Any suggestions as to how I should approach this (calling an abstract method during instantiation)? Design pattern or design changes? Use the repeated call in the Child? Thanks :)

Comment: First hello OshaGoro! That is a very good formulated question, and in that regard, you did well for your first one! :)

Comment: Thank you! <3
Still finding my way around, but I appreciate it!

Comment: When every `Child` has `x` then `x` belongs to `Parent`, not `Child`. Move `x` to `Parent` and create a constructor with a parameter for it.

Comment: If every child class has `x` then it  should be defined in `Parent` class. You can have a setter method so as sub classes can set its value. Or you could mark it with access modifier as `protected`. **Now regarding the invoking overridden field-getter method from constructor of Parent class doesn't make sense as if the field is not set by parent then always you will get the default value only.** Overridden method as a good practice shouldn't be invoked from constructor.

Answer (score 1):

As akuzminykh correctly stated, if the `x` field is part of all classes derived from `Parent`, then the field is a `Parent` field. However sometimes this is not the case, and then you would want the child fields to be set, before the parent is completely living.

This is a common problem in instantiation order, and as you stated correctly:

> [...] there is an issue because the x field hasn't been set when getX() is called in the parent from super() [...]

Due to this, that kind of call cannot be made inside a parent constructor. There are some common approaches to this, most involving some kind of `init()` method being called, after the instance has been completely constructed.

One pattern doing this (without the use of heavy weight dependency injection) is the factory pattern. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm for detailed information.

The Factory pattern is designed in such a way, that an instance is not only created by a constructor, but ultimately returned by a factory, which is given values that are used for instantiation. That factory can guarantee the call of an `init`-method, after the instance is completed.

```java
abstract class Parent {
    // Notice the protected modifier!
    protected Parent() {
        // field initializations of Parent.
    }

    protected void init() {
        // I replaced print with System.out.println here ot make it compile.
        System.out.println(getX());
    }

    public abstract int getX();
}

abstract class ParentFactory<T extends Parent> {
    public abstract T instance();
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    private int x;

    protected Child(int x) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}

class ChildFactory extends ParentFactory<Child> {

    int x = 0;

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public Child instance() {
        Child instance = new Child(x);
        instance.init();
        return instance;
    }
}

@Test
public void test() {
    ChildFactory factory = new ChildFactory();
    factory.setX(7);
    Child child = factory.instance();
    System.out.println("And child has x: " + child.x);
}
```

Notice that this kind of factory (a stateful factory) is very similar to a Builder from the Builder pattern. It is different only in that it is usually reused, rather than created on the spot. You can vary this pattern in that there is also an explicit method in `ChildFactory` which takes explicit parameters over the state-fields of ChildFactory:

```java
public Child instance(int x) {
    Child instance = new Child(x);
    instance.init();
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Ahh interesting. This makes sense so far. How would it look if more subclasses of Parent were to be introduced? Say for example, Child2 and Child3. Would there have to be separate factories (such as Child2Factory and Child3Factory) required for each one? If so, would this typically be an issue if there were to be a large number of subclasses or is this acceptable? Hopefully I'm understanding this correctly. Thank you for this btw :)

Comment: There are similar patterns with the same name. Factory can mean a specific factory per instantiated class (as in my example) with a specific instantiation method, or it can be a class that can create different instances, but an instantiation method would have to be implemented explicitly for each instance. I find neither of these appealing. Since the factory pattern creates implementation overhead, using it is a bit bulky. If you can avoid the need for calling child attributes in constructors altogether, then I'd suggest that (as others have hinted).